# Why does pensquare end lines at an angle?

Tags: metapost

For example:

```
path p[];
p1 := (0,0)--(5cm,0)--(5cm,5cm);
p2 := p1 shifted (7cm,0);
p3 := p2 shifted (7cm,0);
p4 := p3 shifted (7cm,0);
p5 := p4 shifted (7cm,0);

linecap := squared;
pickup pencircle scaled 1cm; draw p1 withcolor red;
pickup pencircle scaled 1bp; draw p1;

pickup pencircle scaled 1cm; draw p2 withcolor red;
pickup pencircle scaled 1bp; draw p2;

pickup pensquare scaled 1cm; draw p3 withcolor red;
pickup pensquare scaled 1bp; draw p3;

linejoin := mitered;
pickup pensquare scaled 1cm; draw p4 withcolor red;
pickup pensquare scaled 1bp; draw p4;

linecap := butt;
linejoin := mitered;
pickup pencircle scaled 1cm; draw p5 withcolor red;
pickup pencircle scaled 1bp; draw p5;
```

Produces:

[image]

The third drawing the one that isn't what I was expecting.

Comment: I think the linecap is mainly meant for the circular pen.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

@mickep's comment is correct; the setting of `linecap` is really meant for the default circular pen.  This picture is my attempt to explain what is going on.

[image]

This shows what happens with the default pen `pencircle` under different settings of `linecap`.  In the middle, shaded slightly darker, you can see the default setting of `linecap := rounded`.  The grey line shows my test path drawn with `pencircle` scaled to `1cm`, the red line shows the same path draw with the default `pencircle` scaled to 0.5pt.  The thin black line is the `envelope` of the path and the pen.  Finally I have drawn the outline of the pen in blue at each point of the test path.

On the left you can see what happens with `linecap := butt`.  MP has cut off the path by drawing across the middle of the pen.  On the right, with `linecap := squared`, this same line across the middle of the pen, has been pushed out in the direction of the path to the far edge of the pen.

Now compare this same drawing with two other pens.  The top row is `pensquare scaled 1cm`, the lower row is `pensquare scaled 1cm rotated 45`.

[image]

With a little imagination, you can see that the same procedure has been followed for the line caps.  With `linecap := rounded`, the ends are not actually "rounded" at all, they are simply made by drawing the pen on the points at the end of the path.  And with `linecap := butt` the ends have been made by cutting across the middle of the pen, which happens in the first case to make a 45° angle.  And you can see the same effect with `linecap := squared` which again appears to be the line across the middle of the pen pushed out to the far edge of the pen.

So to answer the OP question: if you have set a non-default `linecap`, you will find that `pensquare` lines end at an angle because the line capping routine was designed for the default circular pen.

One possible mitigation if you really want lines drawn with a very thick `pensquare` and `linecap` set to `butt` or `squared` is to rotate the pen by 45° as shown, so that the line across the middle of the pen is orthogonal to the direction of the path.

For completeness here is my MP source for the diagrams (which you can compile with `lualatex`).

```
\documentclass[border=5mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{luamplib}
\begin{document}
\mplibtextextlabel{enable}
\begin{mplibcode}
beginfig(1);
    numeric u; u = 1cm;
    pen P[];
    P1 = makepen(for i=1 upto 90: 1/2 dir 4i -- endfor cycle) scaled u;
    P2 = pensquare scaled u;
    P3 = pensquare scaled u rotated 45;
    path crook; crook = origin -- (5u, 0) -- 8u * dir 42;
    string name[];
    name[butt] = "butt";
    name[rounded] = "rounded";
    name[squared] = "squared";
    for cap = rounded, butt, squared:
        interim linecap := cap;
        for j = 1, 2, 3:
            pair s; s = (cap, -j) scaled 8u;
            draw crook shifted s withpen P[j] withcolor (15/16 if cap=rounded: - 1/8 fi);
            draw envelope P[j] of crook shifted s; 
            for k=0, 1, 2:
                draw makepath(P[j]) shifted point k of crook shifted s withcolor blue;
            endfor
            draw crook shifted s withcolor red;
            label(name[cap], s + 40 up);
        endfor
    endfor
endfig;
\end{mplibcode}
\end{document}
```

### Note

- You can only use `envelope` with a polygonal pen, so I have `P1 = makepen(for i=1 upto 90: 1/2 dir 4i -- endfor cycle) scaled u` instead of `P1 = pencircle scaled u`.  A 90-sided regular polygon looks pretty much the same as a circle...